# Flutter: Align text right and left with space within row

Tags: flutter, text, alignment, row

I want to align 2 different text widgets on opposite sides of a page (with space between the end of the page and the text).
I tried the following:

```
       Column(
       children: [
          Row(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: const Alignment(-0.9, 0),
              child: Text(
                card.subCategory,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: const Alignment(0.9, 0),
              child: Text(
                DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(card.createdOn.toDate()),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

but it piles everything to the right as follows: [image: text using rows]

but what I want is something closer to the following: [image: text using columns]

which I got with the following code:

```
      Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: const Alignment(-0.9, 0),
          child: Text(
            card.subCategory,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: const Alignment(0.9, 0),
          child: Text(
            DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(card.createdOn.toDate()),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
```

The closest I got was by adding mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween to the row widget as follows:

```
         Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(-0.5, 0),
            child: Text(
              card.subCategory,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(0.5, 0),
            child: Text(
              DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(card.createdOn.toDate()),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          )
        ])
```

but it doesn't add padding/space between the edges of the phone and the text: [image: using mainAxisAllignment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Align`, use `mainAxisAlignment` (without using `Align`). Using both is redundant since they both work to align your children along the main axis of the `Row`. If you want padding only on the text and not on the rounded chip (i.e. only the line of text with "1x30" and the date), just wrap that `Row` in `Padding`:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          const Text("1x30", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
          Text(
            DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    // This is the rounded chip you have below the line of text.
    const DetailsChip(),
  ],
)
```

This builds the following:
[image: Simulator screenshot with padding only on text]

However, I would recommend adding an offset from the edge of the entire screen, which is more consistent with design conventions. In this case, just add `Padding` around the entire screen and add a `SizedBox` between the text row and the rounded chip:

```
// Move this padding to wrap the widget defining the entire screen.
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          const Text("1x30", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
          Text(
            DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
      // This is the rounded chip you have below the line of text.
      const DetailsChip(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image: Simulator screenshot with padding on entire screen]